# how to scan only particular part of the code to replace a variable in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

file: Define_variable.sql

```
DEFINE schema_name = ms
```

file: insert_data.sql

```
insert into &schema_name.settings(key,value) values('Email_msg','<html><p>Dear  {First_Name}, {Last_Name}</p><p>{End_user_organization_name} has decided to embrace a new technology. Once enrolled, your Android&#8482; or S<sup>&reg;</sup> </html>')
```

i need to insert the value in a table, but i was not able to do it.

It is asking for the value of &reg ( inside the html script).If i put scan off, it is not picking &schema_name, and if i put scan on, itis asking for the value inside html. Is there any way to do

Note: the column value is a Clob data and contains a big html template, for sample purpose , i have enclosed only a few html content.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the character to use in substitution variables; for example:

```
SQL> set define @
SQL> define my_variable=value
SQL> select '&my_variable=@my_variable' from dual;
old   1: select '&my_variable=@my_variable' from dual
new   1: select '&my_variable=value' from dual

'&MY_VARIABLE=VALU
------------------
&my_variable=value
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra `.` to terminate the substitution variable:

```
insert into &schema_name..settings (key,value)
```

Substitution variables are optionally terminated by `.` so if you want an actual dot after it then you need two.

btw `scan` has been obsolete and deprecated for as long as I can remember. Use `set define`, which also allows you to set a different prefix character.